# How To Save Unicode Right-To-Left File File So Formatting Retains?

Tags: java, formatting, unicode, mobile-phone, right-to-left

I want to save **hebrew text with right-to-left direction** into a **.TXT** or **.HTML** file but what retains is only Unicode but not right-to-left formatting. My phone (Sony Ericsson W850i) is not a smartphone but supports Java and cannot read Microsoft Word documents.

Comment: This isn't about an end-user application at all. I'm not sure how it it's on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer to my question here:
http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/